# Why can't I navigate to the page for creating database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am following the tutorial from this page(http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/creating-an-app-from-scratch-part-2/). I am trying to create database by following this address:

`http://localhost/phpmyadmin`

but "This webpage is not available" in my browser.

I downloaded XAMPP and started "MySQL", but still can't access to the page. Is there something I should download to access the page? What are they? I am using Windows7. Thanks.

Comment: Have you setup phpMyAdmin on your development server?

Comment: While that tutorial at least has the decency to use PDO and SQL placeholders, it's awfully low-level and limited. A better approach would be to use a
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/).

Comment: @tadman you still need to set up an environment before you can develop using a framework.

Comment: try to find out your localhost's IP by typing `ipconfig` in your command prompt ("windows key" + R then type `cmd` to get to the prompt). look at the `IPv4 Address`. then try it using your IP: `http://192.168.x.x/phpmyadmin`.

Comment: @tadman I myself am awfully low-level in creating an app, so there's still lots of things for me to learn from this..But thanks for the suggestion:)

Comment: @BrianDriscoll Would you mind elaborating what you meant by development server?...I certainly didn't install phpMyAdmin.

Comment: @everypeas XAMPP installer should have installed phpMyAdmin. See my answer as I believe it addresses your issue.

Comment: @northkildonan I tried it and still can't access.

Comment: @everypeas Don't confuse "getting started" with needing to go low-level. Laravel is very friendly to new developers and is a lot easier than flailing about with PHP primitives. Once you get your development environment running, that'd be the way to develop an application, no matter how simple.

Comment: I agree with tadman Laravel is a great framework and can help you get started on your development path quickly, but it doesn't _really_ solve your current problem.

Answer (score 1):

The issue, assuming you're on Windows, is that IIS is currently running and listening for requests on port 80 on your local machine. As a corollary, Apache is probably NOT running. So, to fix the issue you'll need to stop IIS and start Apache.

**Stop IIS**

1. Start a new command prompt.
2. At the command prompt, type `net stop w3svc`

**Start Apache**

1. Start a new command prompt (or use existing).
2. Navigate to your XAMPP installation folder (e.g. C:\xampp).
3. Type `apache_start` at the command prompt

Comment: I typed "net stop w3svc" and it says the service name is incorrect (Roughly translated in to English). What should I do?

Comment: Are you using Windows as your operating system? What is your language?

Comment: I am using Windows7. The language is Korean.

Comment: You may need to run the command prompt as Administrator. You can also try `net stop WAS`, which will prompt you to stop W3SVC.

Comment: You can also use the UI to stop services: Start->Administrative Tools->Services

Comment: I was already running the command prompt as Administrator. I tried to find my ways around to stop the service but couldn't, so instead I just started Apache without stopping IIS. Now I can access the page. Problem solved. Thanks! :)